# While Ejs file doesn't see css style?

Tags: css, express, ejs

Have problem in my express app. Have some ejs templates, where css style file applied correctly. For example "localhost***/page", but when i go to "localhost***/page/secondpage" my ejs doesn't see style even if i apply it.

A little bit of code
app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//some code
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/events', require('./routes/events'));
```

some routes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    let query = *db query*;
    res.locals.connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.render('index', { title: 'Events', data: results });
    });
});

router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
    let query = *db query*;
    res.locals.connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.render('singleevent', { title: 'Event', data: results });
    });
});
```

Head of localhost***/events page and of next page localhost***/events/singleevent

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>
    <%= title %>|Minsk Events</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
```

[There are my dirs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npZj7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You asked for css file related to the html file.

So if html file is placed under events, then css file should be at:
/events/css/style.css
etc.

Comment: in default directory i have: public/css/style.css
and views/events.ejs, and views/singleevent.ejs